# finding max of 3 scores then writing the max to a text file

Tags: python, string, sorting, text, python-3.4

I am going to use this code to sort scores in descending order.

I plan to define both as functions and use them when needed, the second piece of code which starts after the first `print` function will find the max value of a text file. I then want it to save this value to a new text file.

However whenever I try to do this it gives me an error message, I must be able to keep the string that is attached to the number, this is so the teacher can identify whose score it is.

```
import operator

sort_key = operator.itemgetter(0)

with open('3a.txt','r') as fo:
    split_lines = (line.split(None, 1) for line in fo)
    numeric_lines = ((int(line[0]), line[1]) for line in split_lines)
    sorted_x = sorted(numeric_lines, key=sort_key, reverse=True)

print(sorted_x)

with open('3a.txt','r') as fo:
    split_lines = (line.split(None, 1) for line in fo)
    numeric_lines = ((int(line[0]), line[1]) for line in split_lines)
    sorted_x = max(numeric_lines, key=sort_key)
    sorted_x = list(sorted_x)
with open('1a.txt') as fo:
    fo.write(str(sorted_x))


print(sorted_x)
```

My text file looks like this

```
8 Thomas
4 Thomas
7 Thomas
```

Basically I need to find the max of 3 people's last 3 scores on my quiz and then compare them in descending order.

error message:

```
fo.write(str(sorted_x))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because the file `1a.txt` doesn't exist, and because you didn't specify a mode to `open()` Python attempts to open it in read mode. So you just need to open it in `'w'` mode.

I assume you'd like the new file to be written with a similar format to the input data. So try this:

```
import operator

sort_key = operator.itemgetter(0)    
#sort_key = lambda s:s[0]

with open('3a.txt','r') as fo:
    split_lines = (line.split(None, 1) for line in fo)
    numeric_lines = ((int(line[0]), line[1]) for line in split_lines)
    sorted_x = sorted(numeric_lines, key=sort_key, reverse=True)

print(sorted_x)

with open('3a.txt','r') as fo:
    split_lines = (line.split(None, 1) for line in fo)
    numeric_lines = ((int(line[0]), line[1]) for line in split_lines)
    sorted_x = max(numeric_lines, key=sort_key)
    #sorted_x = list(sorted_x)

print(sorted_x)    

with open('1a.txt','w') as fo:
    fo.write('{0} {1}'.format(*sorted_x))
```

I've included an alternate `sort_key` function that doesn't require you to import `operator`. Also, I commented out that `sorted_x = list(sorted_x)` line since it's not really necessary, and tuples are preferred over lists for immutable data.

Comment: No worries, @pythonlegend232. In future, remember to include _all_ relevant info in your question, including the full Traceback printed for each error, and try to avoid mentioning irrelevant stuff. That way you're less likely to get downvotes (I didn't downvote you, BTW). The [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page has great advice. Remember, your questions here aren't just about helping you, they should be written so that they will help others in the future, too.